# Website "vCard-ish" presentation

Tags: html

I'm not sure how common this implementation is but some time ago I saw a couple of sites having text or html file(s) that allowed for meta data to be gathered about external links.

In example (fictive); if I linked a post to YouTube a request was sent to the address and gathered some basic information given by the external server presenting text and a logotype that was embedded on the site I was posting on.

What is this called?

One service I definitely remember implementing this was Battlefield Battlelog, if a link was posted in the feed, Battlelog would send a request to the external server and present the external information including 2 rows of text and a logotype below the link.

I would say it's some sort of vCard, at the time I also think I looked it up to be W3C Standard/RFC.

**Edit:** Closest match I could find is [Open Graph](http://ogp.me), if there is no W3C alternative this is it.

Comment: Are you referring to what SO calls Flair?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I did some lookup on SO but I don't "flair" is what I'm looking for. Flair is more of a manual way of implementing this, what I'm looking for is automated.

Comment: Kind of like what https://gravatar.com/ does?

Comment: @TajMorton Yes, if you see the header-section with the profile presentation of "Matt" - that is very much alike. I manage to find [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) but that seems to be some Facebook non-html5 implementation. But maybe this is what I was looking for. I'm just so sure about it being a w3 standard concept.